# Google Chart is not displaying in IE9.0 though its works fine in IE7,IE8

Tags: jquery, google-visualization

In my project i am working with Google maps and Google Charts. Google charts are working fine in all the browsers except IE9.0..i am not able to see charts if i select my browser is IE9, when i change BrowserMode to IE7 or IE8 i am able to see Charts..Please help.

Comment: We need some code to look at, or first just tell us what program your using to cross-browser test IE.

Comment: Hi Jackson,Google charts in my application working fine in IE7, then i installed IE9 and executed application, the problem is i am able to see Google maps and Table reports except Google Charts in my Page..Please help.

Comment: Your former comment is a jumbled mess, but the first problem I see is this: `src='google.com/jsapi'></script>;`

What is that? src should be a url to a .js file with http://.

Comment: If you're looking to load jsapi, it should be this:

src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"

Comment: Can you link to your website?

Comment: <script type='text/javascript' src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I saw it wrong you had it right before, and what you just posted works as well. (the difference being the ""'s). Anyway, can you link to the site?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Although, why is this question tagged 'JQuery'?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the `google.load` package name is `corechart` as seen here:
`google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});`